# How to get current record id in wrapper class

Tags: apex, compile-error

I am trying add to add multiple objects in a list. So I created a wrapper list. I'm getting current leadid But when I try to add to wrapper list I get this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   add(WrapperDistance.MyWrapper) from the type WrapperDistance.MyWrapper

My Class:

```
public class WrapperDistance {
    public String CurrentId;
    public Set<String> codes,States,cities;
    public List<Opportunity> listopp{get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> Mainlist;
    public List<MyWrapper> wrapper {get; set;}

    public WrapperDistance(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        CurrentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    public void search()
    {
        for(Lead ld:[Select Id,City,State,SIC_Code_1__c,Latitude,Longitude from Lead where Id=:CurrentId ])
        {
            Latitudes=ld.Latitude;
            Longtitudes=ld.Longitude;
        }
        for (Opportunity opp:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                              Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                              account.No_of_active_units__c,account.BillingLatitude,account.BillingLongitude from opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                              LIKE :codes and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
        {
            if(opp.account.SIC_Code__c <> null)
            {
                Temporary.add(opp);
                Location loc1 = Location.newInstance(Latitudes,Longtitudes);
                Location loc2 = Location.newInstance(opp.account.BillingLatitude,opp.account.BillingLongitude);
                Total = Location.getDistance(loc1, loc2, 'mi');
                MyWrapper wrapped= new MyWrapper(opp,Total);
                MyWrapper.add(wrapped); 
            }

        }
    }
    public class MyWrapper
    {
        public Opportunity oppRec {get; set;}
        public Double Totaldis {get; set;}

        public MyWrapper(Opportunity oppw , Double disw)
        {
            oppRec = oppw ;
            Totaldis = disw ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow your title does not match your question, please adjust.

Comment: You are very much not new to Visualforce. Your first question on that tag is from September 2015. Please don't lie about it. Even if you were new to VF, that information would be completely irrelevant to the question at hand. Please also try to keep your post limited to information which is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typo, try:

```
wrapper.add(wrapped);
```